# Use map function from the Observable's emitted value's own property in RxJs

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

Is there any way to use a map function in RxJs from the observable's emitted value's property?

Let's say I have an Observable of type:  `Observable<Something>`, and  `Something` has a property called  `mapFunction` with the value:  `mapTo({ isTicking: true })`. Is there anyway I can use this map function on that observable? Like this:

`private composingObs$ = this.streamOfSomethings$.pipe( // I would like to use the instance function: something.mapFunction as map here.`

Comment: Are you trying to map a function over the observables from `streamOfSomethings`?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that the mapping function is in a property of the "something" instance, which is not available until after streamOfSomethings$ been mapped.

Comment: Can you show us more code..? I can't really understand this

Comment: Could you post your code snippet for a clear understanding? @user10103655

Answer (score 1):

This will probably work. It fetch the function once, then subsequent emission will be handled by `something.someFn` which according to you is an operator `mapTo`

```
this.streamOfSomethings$.pipe(
take(1),
mergeMap(something=>this.streamOfSomethings$.pipe(something.someFn))
)
```

Although i think you should use general function or observable as property other than pipable functions, that will give you more flexibilities.

you can setup somethingObject as `{data:..., fn:...}`

```
somethingObject.pipe(map(({data,fn)=>fn(data)));
```